# Merge two association lists with running accumulator

Tags: haskell

Basically, I would describe this as a union/merge of `[(,)]` combined with a running accummulator on `snd` of the pair...  Is there an elegant way to implement this?

(Please reference my code only in the context of answering the question. If you want to review my code, that would be great too, but please do that on this other site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54993/merging-time-series)

A time series,

```
data Model a where
  Variant  :: [(Day, a)] -> Model a
  deriving (Show)
```

... where type `a` in `[(Day, a)]` basically represents the "total balance" e.g. bank account.

Some example data,

```
day1 = fromGregorian 1987 10 17
day2 = fromGregorian 1987 10 18
day3 = fromGregorian 1987 10 19
day4 = fromGregorian 1987 10 20
day5 = fromGregorian 1987 10 21
day6 = fromGregorian 1987 10 22

m1 = Variant [(day1, 1), (day3, 3), (day5, 5)] :: Model Integer
m2 = Variant [(day1, 1), (day2, 2), (day4, 4), (day6, 6)] :: Model Integer
```

Now, merge two time series such that the "total balance" is additive,

```
(&+) :: Num a => Model a -> Model a -> Model a
(Variant a) &+ (Variant b) = Variant $ reverse $ fst $ go a b ([],0)
  where
    go             []             [] (xs, c) = (xs, c)
    go   ((da,va):as)             [] (xs, c) = go as [] (((da,va+c):xs), va+c)
    go             []   ((db,vb):bs) (xs, c) = go [] bs (((db,vb+c):xs), vb+c)
    go a@((da,va):as) b@((db,vb):bs) (xs, c)
      | da > db  = go  a bs (((db,vb+c):xs), vb+c)
      | da < db  = go as  b (((da,va+c):xs), va+c)
      | da == db = go as bs (((da,va+vb+c):xs), va+vb+c)
```

So,

```
what = m1 &+ m2

Variant [(1987-10-17,2),(1987-10-18,4),(1987-10-19,7),(1987-10-20,11),(1987-10-21,16),(1987-10-22,22)]
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're always adding `c`? This doesn't feel like it would be doing the "right" thing w.r.t. cumulative metrics.

Comment: If you were to use `Data.Map.Map` instead of a list then that module has a handy `unionWith` function for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The moment I saw `reverse` I felt there might be trouble. Here's a version which is lazier and works on infinite values. It does depend upon each of its inputs as being sorted by `Day`, however. First we seek to `merge` the two streams

```
merge :: Num a => Model a -> Model a -> Model a
merge (Variant xs) (Variant ys) = Variant (go xs ys) where
  go [] ys = ys
  go xs [] = xs
  go xx@((dx, vx):xs) yy@((dy, vy):ys)
    | dx < dy   = (dx, vx)      : go xs yy
    | dx > dy   = (dy, vy)      : go xx ys
    | otherwise = (dx, vx + vy) : go xs ys
```

It's basically the core of what you had, but much simpler. Typically, if you can make a computation lazy in Haskell then it's worth the effort as it may be more efficient. After this point, we'll accumulate

```
accum :: Num a => Model a -> Model a
accum (Variant xs) = Variant (go xs 0) where
  go []          _ = []
  go ((d, v):xs) c = let c' = v + c in (d, c') : go xs c'
```

And then combining these two we get the desired result

```
-- (&+) :: Num a => Model a -> Model a -> Model a
-- a &+ b = accum (merge a b)
```

Though, it might be better to leave `merge` and `accum` as the exposed API since they can be combined in many ways other than just `(&+)`.

---

It may be worth noting that the obvious way to  write the `accum` function as a right fold

```
accum' :: Num a => Model a -> Model a
accum' (Variant xs) = Variant (snd $ foldr go (0, []) xs) where
  go (d, v) (c, res) = let c' = v + c in (c', (d, c'):res)
```

doesn't work because it accumulates the parameter from the rear of the list. Trying the left fold works but we have to reverse the list—a double sin against laziness.

```
accum'' :: Num a => Model a -> Model a
accum'' (Variant xs) = Variant (reverse $ snd $ foldl go (0, []) xs) where
  go (d, v) (c, res) = let c' = v + c in (c', (d, c'):res)
```

which gives a hint as to what was happening in the original version. We can write this as a right fold, however, but we have to be a little tricky in order to pass the accumulator in the right direction

```
accum' :: Num a => Model a -> Model a
accum' (Variant xs) = Variant (foldr go (const []) xs 0) where
  go (d, v) rest c = let c' = v + c in (d, c') : rest c'
```

Note here that the result of `foldr go (const []) xs` is a value of type `a -> [a]`.

Comment: This implementation doesn't accumulate the `snd' of the pair.. the type ```a```.  Basically, I have an alist [(Day, a)] where I want to do a union on ```fst``` and an accumulator on ```snd```.  Please see the value of ```what```.

Comment: I re-ran the code after your edit, and it still looks like the value of ```what``` is not as expected...  I will now try to understand what you're saying about laziness though.

Comment: I had a typo in the updated code, but it is correct: `m1 &+ m2 == accum (merge m1 m2)` produces `True`.

Comment: I believe the original implementation is attempting to be tail-recursive. this version removes that speedup.

Comment: Tail recursive doesn't necessarily mean faster code in Haskell. Usually you're better off writing lazy, productive code.

Comment: In my (admittedly limited) experience, lazy is great for expressiveness and being super clever, but rarely good for speed. It's a great way to fill your heap with thunks though.

Comment: Being too lazy can be expensive just as can being too strict. In this case, Haskell basically turns lazy productions like this into generators and consumes them in constant space linear time.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Don't you think `accum` function will occupy more memory as `v + c` isn't being forced there ?

Comment: It will if you run through many elements of the list without viewing their value. Printing them won't cause issues though. It might be useful to strictify the type: I'd likely use a strict pair if this were performance sensitive code.

Comment: Whenever we need a (non-existent) lazy left fold, left scan usually helps: `accum (Variant xs) = Variant $ zip (map fst xs) (tail $ scanl (+) 0 $ map snd xs)`.

Comment: @WillNess That's pretty. I really ought to get `scanl` more deeply into my mental toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

The association list here is actually a "red herring". This is really a more general question of how to do a merge using a function to combine terms with equal keys. The association list version is the same question, but with a pre-applied [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Stated this way, we want a function with this type:

```
mergeCombineWith :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

where the first parameter defines the ordering and the second parameter is the combining function to be applied to elements with equal keys. We assume that the input lists are pre-sorted. If we also assume that neither of the input lists has any duplicate keys, or that we also want to combine duplicates within the same input list, then the solution is simple. Given a traditional merge function, of type:

```
mergeWith :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

then our desired function is obtained by grouping the results of the traditional merge:

```
mergeCombineWith cmp comb xs ys =
    map combs . groupBy eq $ mergeWith cmp xs ys
  where
    combs = foldr1 comb
    eq x y = isEQ $ cmp x y
    isEQ EQ = True
    isEQ _  = False
```

More generally, it would be interesting to consider merging many lists, not just two. That could be done in a straightforward way using a fold:

```
multiMergeCombineWith :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> (a -> a -> a) -> [[a]] -> [a]
multiMergeCombineWith cmp comb = foldr1 $ mergeCombineWith cmp comb
```

But that solution would be inefficient if there are many lists to combine. A better way would be to put the lists into a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) and always examine first the lists whose first elements are smallest in the given ordering. There are several good priority queue implementations on Hackage.

However, once again, if you have a solution to the multi-list problem for a traditional merge, you don't need to re-invent the wheel. First do the traditional merge, then group and combine, as above.

Thanks to Daniel Wagner for pointing out to me that versions of the two traditional merge functions can be found in the [data-ordlist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist) package on Hackage, called there [mergeBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.6.1/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v%3amergeBy) and [mergeAllBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.6.1/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v%3amergeAllBy).

EDIT: A new priority queue implementation was recently [published on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/psqueues).See the discussion about it in [this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/28vev9/announcing_psqueues_faster_priority_search_queues/).

Comment: This is more than just "a merge using a function to combine terms with equal keys."  Please see the value of ```map snd what```... it is an accumulator that is stored for every element as the lists are traversed.